# Calculating digits of $\pi$ using partial sums of the power series of arctan

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to solve an exercise regarding the calculation of $\pi$ via power sums, but I am puzzled by the wording of a question.

> a) Show that $(5+i)^4(239-i)$ is a real positive multiple of $1+i$
>
> b) Show Machin's Formula: 
>   $$\frac{\pi}{4}=4 \arctan \frac{1}{5}-\arctan \ \frac{1}{239}$$
>   c) Find the power series of arctan around 0. This can be done for 
>   instance by integrating the power series of its derivative.
>   d) Use partial sums for arctan to calculate estimates for $\pi$. How does this method compare to calculating estimates via $\pi=4 \arctan(1)$?

I solved a)-c) but have gotten stuck at d). I know from c) that the power series of $\arctan$ at $0$ is given by

$$\arctan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

But I am at a loss what to do next, as I do not see how to calculate $\pi$ in any other way than using

$$\pi=\arctan(1)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

Can somebody explain what is supposed to be done here or how this is question is solved?

Comment: There's no d). It seems you forgot to precede the last paragraph in the problem statement with "d)"?

Comment: Yes. I forgot the letter d). I have added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it’s just asking you to substitute $\frac15$ and $\frac1{239}$ into the series to get approximations for $\pi$ and to note that the convergence is much better than for $\arctan1$ because of the additional factor of $\frac1{25}$ per step.